# Do Gromov hyperbolic spaces admit concical geodesic bicombings?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, metric-spaces, set-valued-analysis

Consider a metric space $(X,d)$ with a distinguished selection of geodesics, i.e. a [geodesic bicombing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_bicombing) $\sigma:X\times X\times [0,1]\rightarrow X$.  We call a geodesic bicombing *conical* if it satisfies the following "convexity-type condition"
$$
d(\sigma_{xy}(t), \sigma_{x^\prime y^\prime}(t))\leq (1-t)d(x,x^\prime)+t d(y,y^\prime)
$$
for all $x,x',y,y'\in X$ and $t\in [0,1]$.

---

If $(X,d)$ is a complete, separable, contractible Gromov ($\delta$) hyperbolic intrinsic metric space, for some $\delta>0$, then does $(X,d)$ admit a conical geodesic bicombing?

Comment: This condition implies contractibility of $X$, are you sure that you really mean it?

Comment: I think you should write "Gromov-hyperbolic" rather than $\delta$-hyperbolic. $\delta$ is a parameter, which does not play any role in your question.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Ah, in the case I had in mind, my space is a contracible ANR which is additionally $\delta$-hyperbolic.  Otherwise, yes, I would not have a shot.

Comment: Ok, there is still an easy counter-example: take the unit sphere with the standard (Riemannian) metric and remove a point from it. Maybe you are making further assumptions to rule out such examples. Note that metric completeness is not enough (remove a small open disk from the unit sphere).

Comment: @MoisheKohan Fair, I'm also assuming its a polish space.  In fact, its a specific remetrization of the hyperspace of compact subsets of a finite-dimensional closed convex subset of a Banach space.  This:
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X16301007

But in particular (i added this since it is important) it is polish.

Comment: As I explained, the added assumptions are insufficient. Maybe you should explain in detail the actual example you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks Moise.  I also have some doubts due to this article: https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.12681 In the final section, the authors cast doubt on the existence of a conical bicombing (even in a simple case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of your extra assumptions will suffice. An easy example is obtained as follows. Start with the unit 2-sphere $S^2$ with the standard Riemannian metric $ds^2$ induced from the embedding in ${\mathbb R}^3$.  Remove from $S^2$ a small open metric disk (of radius $<\pi/2$, cetered at a point $p\in S^2$). Equip the resulting space $X$ with the length structure coming from $ds^2$. The corresponding metric $d$ on $X$ will be complete, etc, since $X$ is  compact. However, it is clear that $(X,d)$ fails the required convexity property:  Take the point $x=-p$. Then every $y\in (X,d)$ is connected to $x$ by a unique geodesic. But the convexity property fails for such geodesics (just look at $y, y'$ which belong to the boundary circle of $X$).